# Python OpenGL control ball under Gravity effect

Tags: python, opengl

I have a Problem in code with OpenGl in python, i need to control the movement of the ball in y-axis .the ball is under the gravity effect but when button is pressed the ball jump a bit up ,but when not pressed the ball falls down 
this is like color alter / color switch game .
The problem is when i press the button once the ball keep going up and when press any another button it goes down .

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

def KB(Key, x, y):
    global pressed
    if Key == b"u":
        pressed = True
    else:
        pressed = False
    if Key == b"q":
        sys.exit()

yy = -0.07
dt = 0.0005
v_velocity = 3
xx = 0
max = False
pressed = False

def drw():
    global xx, max, v_velocity, dt, yy, pressed
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glColor(1, 0, 0)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glTranslate(xx, 0.4, 0)
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)  # The Line
    glVertex2d(-0.8, 0.1)
    glVertex2d(-0.8, -0.1)
    glVertex2d(-0.2, -0.1)
    glVertex2d(-0.2, 0.1)
    glEnd()
    glColor(0, 1, 0)
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)  # The Line
    glVertex2d(-0.2, 0.1)
    glVertex2d(-0.2, -0.1)
    glVertex2d(0.4, -0.1)
    glVertex2d(0.4, 0.1)
    glEnd()
    glColor(0, 0, 1)
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2d(0.4, 0.1)  # The Line
    glVertex2d(0.4, -0.1)
    glVertex2d(0.8, -0.1)
    glVertex2d(0.8, 0.1)
    glEnd()

    glLoadIdentity()
    glTranslate(0, yy, 0)
    glColor(0, 1, 0)
    glutSolidSphere(0.07, 25, 25)  # The ball

    # movement of the Line

    if xx > 1.5:
        max = True
    if xx < -1.5:
        max = False
    if max:
        xx -= 0.0005
    else:
        xx += 0.0005
    # ????? movement of the Ball  ???????
    if pressed:
        yy += 0.0007
    else:
        v_velocity = v_velocity - 9.8 * dt
        yy += v_velocity * dt

    glutSwapBuffers()

glutInit()
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE)
glutInitWindowSize(400, 400)
glutCreateWindow(b"Title")
glutDisplayFunc(drw)
glutKeyboardFunc(KB)
glutIdleFunc(drw)
glutMainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the [`glutKeyboardFunc`](http://openglut.sourceforge.net/group__input.html#ga0) function and the [`glutKeyboardUpFunc`](http://openglut.sourceforge.net/group__input.html#ga2) function.

While [`glutKeyboardFunc`](http://openglut.sourceforge.net/group__input.html#ga0) gives a notification that a key was pressed, [`glutKeyboardUpFunc`](http://openglut.sourceforge.net/group__input.html#ga2) notifies that a key was released.
Set `pressed = True` when the key is pressed and `pressed = False` when the key is released.

Further you should initialize `v_velocity = 0` instead of `v_velocity = 3`.

```
 def KBPressed(Key, x, y):
    global pressed
    if Key == b"p":
        pressed = True
    if Key == b"q":
        sys.exit()

def KBUp(Key, x, y):
    global pressed
    if Key == b"p":
        pressed = False
```

```
glutKeyboardFunc(KBPressed)
glutKeyboardUpFunc(KBUp)
```

Note, you can also use the callback functions for special keys [`glutSpecialFunc`](http://openglut.sourceforge.net/group__input.html#ga1) and [`glutSpecialUpFunc`](http://openglut.sourceforge.net/group__input.html#ga3)

e.g. "up" key:

```
def SKUp(Key, x, y):
    global pressed
    if Key == GLUT_KEY_UP:
        pressed = False

def SKPressed(Key, x, y):
    global pressed
    if Key == GLUT_KEY_UP:
        pressed = True
```

```
glutSpecialFunc(SKPressed)
glutSpecialUpFunc(SKUp)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seen to be because you only set gravity when you don't press the key:

```
if pressed:
    yy += 0.0007
else:
    v_velocity = v_velocity - 9.8 * dt
    yy += v_velocity * dt
```

So it is normal that when you press the button, it will only go up, and if not, it will go down.